# How do you get search engines to treat different data on the page as different pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, search-engine, asp.net-webpages

I have a page on a site which has different data based on the querystring parameter (to differentiate clients)

How do I change this page so that each client's "page" can be individually optimized for search engines, so that their specific URL might show up from a search. Must a new page be created for each client?

for example one client's page is on mysite.com?company=1 and one client's page is mysite.com?company=2. How do I get search engines to differentiate these 2 "pages"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use query string parameters anyways? Create nice pretty routes. Instead of `mysite.com?company=1` use `mysite.com/company/1` or `mysite.com/company/acme-inc`.

Comment: Would changing the routes allow me to optimize them for search independently?

Comment: Sites with the same domain/sub-domain will be treated as the same site in search engines. How about using sub-domains instead? eg. `company1.example.com` and `company2.example.com`. You can have wildcard sub-domains and check what is being requested with `Request.Url.Host`.